# Proving linearity implies (or can imply under opportune conditions) lower semicontinuity

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, continuous-homomorphisms

A function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, with $X$ being a topological space, is termed as *lower semicontinuous (lsc) at $x_0\in X$* if:
$$\forall\epsilon>0\,\,\exists V\text{ an open neighborhood of }x_0:x\in V\implies f(x)>f(x_0)-\epsilon.$$
Equivalently, for any net $x_n\to x_0$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\geq f(x_0)$ (sequences are sufficient in the case of metric spaces $(X,d)$). Suppose $X$ is now a normed space.

- Is linearity sufficient for a function $f$ to be lsc at all points of $X$?
- Do we need $X$ to be Banach (i.e. metrically complete) for that to hold?
- Do we need something more to be satisfied by the function?
- How do I prove anything that emerged from the previous points?

For the moment, I managed to show that for linear functions, lsc-ity in the origin is equivalent to lsc-ity everywhere. I tried then contradicting lsc-ity in the origin, i.e. supposing that:
$$\exists\epsilon>0:\forall\delta>0\,\,\exists x\in X:\|x\|<\delta,f(x)\leq-\epsilon,$$
but did not get anywhere with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

*Proposition.* Let $X$ be a linear topological space and $f:X\to\Bbb R$ be a lower semicontinuous linear function. Then $f$ is continuous.

*Proof*. Since the function $f$is linear, it suffices to show that $f$ is continuous at the origin $0$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be an arbitrary number. Since the function $f$ is lower semicontinuous at the origin, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of the origin such that $f(x)>f(0)-\varepsilon=-\varepsilon$ for each point $x\in V$. Then $V\cap (-V)$ is a neighborhood of the origin and $|f(x)|<\varepsilon $ for each point $x\in V\cap (-V)$. $\square$

Comment: So the answer to my question is: if there are any noncontinuous linear functions, then no, a linear function is not necessarily lsc, for then it would be continuous, hence linearity would imply continuity, which is not the case. When I get to studying my functional analysis notes, I might come back here since I remember this "linearity implies lsc" had to do with proving the uniform boundedness principle (Banach-Steinhaus, I think), but since I don't remember how this was used in the proof, I can't be sure.

Comment: This answers points 1 and 2, and makes me guess upper semicontinuity combined with linearity would yield continuity by a similar argument. Is there any condition implying lsc-ity for linear functions?

Comment: Accepted the answer because it (indirectly) solves the main issue in the question, i.e. whether linearity implies lsc-ity or not.

Comment: @MickG It seems the following. The situation with upper semicontinuity is similar, because a real-valued function $f$ is upper semicontinuous iff a function $-f$ is lower semicontinuous. The problem “ Is there any condition implying lsc-ity for linear functions?” is equivalent to “ Is there any condition implying continuity for linear functions?”. Such a condition is boundedness. About existence of a adiscontinuous linear map, see the [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map).